# Trying create lists with ng-repeat + polymer elements = failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, angularjs-ng-repeat, paper-elements

I'm trying to create a list using directive ng-repeat(angular 1.4) with polymer elements(polymer 1.0), like the example below:

```
<paper-material data-ng-repeat="curso in cursos">
        <div class="lista">
            <paper-item role="listitem">
                <paper-item-body data-ng-click="carregar(curso)">
                    <div class="first-line">{{ curso.nome | uppercase }}</div>
                </paper-item-body>
                <paper-icon-button data-dialog="removeItem" icon="close" data-ng-click="prepararRemover(curso)"></paper-icon-button> 
            </paper-item>
        </div>
</paper-material>
```

The 'cursos' variable is filled on load page by this method using Restangular:

```
$scope.buscarCursos = function() {
        var promise = Restangular.all('cursos').getList();
        promise.then(function (response){ 
            $scope.cursos = response.data;
        });
};
```

On the load page it works ok. But if i call this method again(reloading the list), i get this error on angular:

> console message: "Error: element is undefined".

If i remove all polymer elements and trying to load and reload page again, i don't had any problem.

I'm doing something wrong or is not possible to do that? In Chrome don't had this problem, only in Firefox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to combine Polymer and Angular? In a lot of ways they are competing frameworks. There is an [Angular Material Design implementation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/) that you should probably considering using instead if your sole reason for Polymer is to try and get the Material Design spec into your project.

Comment: One reason to use Polymer with Angular is poor animation performance of  Angular-Material on mobile platforms. Some performance issues resolution was postponed to post1.0 phase and it makes this "mobile first" framework unusable.

Comment: That's more an opinion than an answer. There are several projects working with MD and NG

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @HughGuiney Apparently the OP thought it did. But thanks for the petty downvote

Comment: @JesseCarter I am sorry. I try hard not to downvote. But I came here with the same question and it is frustrating whenever I see somebody "answering" a question by negating its premise. Angular and Polymer CAN be combined successfully, and this answer implies that they can't. The OP may have accepted it but that does not make it useful for the rest of us. Keep in mind that we aren't allowed to have duplicate questions on here. So if somebody wants to ask the same question, it can be closed because this one was technically answered already.